# 3d plot/scatter xyz coordinates from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, 3d, scatter

i have a pd df in the following form:

| x | y | z | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.0 | 0.0 | 4.0 | 1.0 |

the label is a result of clusturing but i can't seem to find a proper way to do a 3D plt.scatter on the df. any ideas? (the data frame is much bigger than this)

Comment: Did you try using [3D scatterplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html)? Please include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: In how far is the label column relevant for your 3D scatterplot problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my best. Maybe it will help you out.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Your data table

```
df = {'x': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'y': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      'z': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  'label': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
#Creating a 3d scatter plot 

def create_3d_scatter(df):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], df['z'], c=df['label'])
    plt.show()
```

#### This is the according [google colab file with the code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F3ShDR0dN5kXXOC22xAoP2Jt5zSToSWj#scrollTo=22eNIZM0PDb_)

Comment: thank you :) that function was very useful!